# uBuntu 22.04.2 suddenly requires no password to login

Tags: login, password

I've been logging in with my password for years. Within the last month the password is no longer required - it logs me on with no other input when I click on my username. After that, it asks for my password to unlock the secure directory. I checked in Settings for my user and under Authentication & Login Automatic Login is off. I'm in the adm group. I have not changed the login or display manager, I'm not in the nopasswd group, It asks for a password for accessing sudo, and I've tried resetting my password, turning on and then off Automatic login. Neither setting seems to make any difference whatsoever. I'm stumped and have been searching for answers online for a week or more.

Comment: This is very strange. I have never seen this problem and can't reproduce it.

Comment: Depending on what your login DM is (gdm3, lightdm) you might have one of the config files showing the AutomaticLoginEnable set as true and not commented out.  The config files are normally found in `/etc/gdm3/` or in `/etc/lightdm/`.  But this is only a guess.

Comment: Check the keyring and remove all records that are about login.

Comment: Did you do [something like this?](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/enable-passwordless-login-ubuntu-18-04/amp/) If so, you can try to undo the changes.

Comment: Thanks Terrance. I don't know what I'm using - just an updated system, probably originally from 20.04 and upgraded since that. I'm pretty sure lightdm is not there because other web pages talking about that reference /etc files that I don't have. I DO have /etc/gdm3, and here are all of the non-commented lines in that file:
[daemon]
WaylandEnable=false
AutomaticLoginEnable=False
AutomaticLogin=mbudd
[security]
[xdmcp]
[chooser]
[debug]
Enable=true

Does anything look amiss there? Many more files in that tree that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Rinzwind, I'm not sure what files you are referencing, but after login, the password prompt that appears is to unlock the keyring.
user68186, I have not done anything in that article. I don't have any group line in /etc/group that contains the string "pass" or the string "login".

Comment: /usr/sbin/gdm3 is running after I'm logged in

Comment: I just learned a bit about keyring and tried deleting the files in ~/.local/share/keyrings. rebooted and this did not affect the automatic login. I don't get a prompt to unlock the keyring - obviously. I also tried changing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf from AutomaticLoginEnable=False  to AutomaticLoginEnable=false
# AutomaticLogin=
And so far this also has not changed the automatic login.

Comment: I would try to comment out those lines in the config file that is in the /etc/gdm3 directory.  I know they say false, but the one line with your login name maybe causing your automatic login to happen.

Comment: Terrance, I just tried that, and also commented the WaylandEnable. No change to the symptoms, unfortunately. It acts like this custom.conf file is not in use?!

Comment: Try reinstalling GDM3 and make sure that it is the default.  During the installation it will ask.  `sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3`

Comment: Terrance. Great idea! But no change in the problem after reinstalling gdm3. I tried it twice, and the first time it seemed to install something involving pam, but I'm not knowledgable enough to remember what. It did not ask anything about making gdm3 the default. Do I need to do something specific to force that? Here is some of the output before I hit "Y":The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-gdm-1.0 libgdm1
Suggested packages:
  libpam-pkcs11
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gdm3 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 libgdm1

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` should allow you to force between LightDM and GDM3.

Comment: Terrance: I tried this command just now and it did not ask any questions. I restarted the machine and it still does not require a password - just a return gets me in. debconf-show gdm3 returns * shared/default-x-display-manager: gdm3
  gdm3/daemon_name: /usr/sbin/gdm3.